# Jquery .load() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I use jquerys .load() function on a webpage. It loads a loader.gif file and then a html document into a specific div. It works in FF, Chrome and Safari but not in IE. I've been searching the web and stll not found an answer to this so I wonder if you can help me. This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loadCat').click(function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");     
        $('#target').html('loading...');
        $('#target').load(this.href);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;   
    });
});
```

EDIT:
This is an example of the html i use:

```
<a href="page.php" class="loadCat">Link</a>
```

When you click the link in IE the loading... appears but not the page.php im trying to load.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What errors are you getting? Can you show an example value of `this.href`?

Comment: perhaps you could show the HTML markup that goes with this jQuery. Also, when you say it doesn't work, can you provide details by what "doesn't work" entails?

Comment: so now i edited the post. sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.loadCat').click(function(){
        var
            targetElement = $("#target"),
            url = this.href + "?" + new Date().getTime(); //To prevent IE caching

        targetElement.html('loading...');
        $.get(url, function(data){
            targetElement.html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Edited...

Comment: Hi Briedis, i get the same problem with this code as well. Works fine in every browser except for IE

Comment: I bet there is an error somewhere else, because jquery is IE compatbilde. What is the error anyways?

Comment: hmm... loading, shows upp and disappear. but the page does not appear. I guess i have to look somewhere else for the error. i just donät have any idea.

Comment: @Briedis: have u got any solution